# Getting no such file error when trying to run Maven wrapper?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I know I have maven installed:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: /home/roschler/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-123-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I *believe* I have maven wrapper properly installed based on the contents of my working directory:

```
$ ls
LICENSE  mvnw  mvnw.cmd  pom.xml  README.md  src
```

Yet when I try to run maven wrapper, I get the following error:

$ ./mvnw

```
bash: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have a carriage return in your script (a dos line ending). Remove that.

Comment: see dos2unix command to convert CRLF to LF

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  Thanks.  I didn't realize mvnw was actually a script and thought it was a binary since it had no extension.  I'll look for that in the future.  I ran dos2unix on it and it fixed it.  If you'd like to reply to my post I'll accept it as the answer.  If you do, might be helpful to mention dos2unix.

Comment: @Matt Thanks.  Already have that on my Linux box but it's good for others to see that suggestion.